# Trigger to generate unique md5 hash before insert

Tags: mysql, triggers, unique-key

I'm trying to create a trigger that will associate an unique random string to every record inserted in a table.

So far I created a trigger, on before insert, that will generate and add the hash to the table. However, I'm wondering how should I go about ensuring this new hash is **unique for my table**.

So far I have the trigger below, but as you can see the uniques part is missing...

```
BEGIN
DECLARE newhash VARCHAR(255);
SELECT MD5(CONCAT(NOW(),RAND())) INTO newhash;
SET NEW.`hash` = newhash;
END
```

Comment: Note that MD5 is broken, I recommend using SHA2 instead `SET NEW.hash = SHA2(CONCAT(salt, RAND()),512)`

Comment: I really only need a big enough random string. I don't see how the extra 8 characters would help me besides being 8 characters longer random string.

Comment: What do you need it for? Use uuid for non security stuff and sha2 for security.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The column should be unique in the table definition and that's it.

In any case, are you sure that you want md5(now || rand)? With reasonable implementations of now and rand, it's highly unlikely that you are going to have duplicates, but if now() doesn't have a lot of granularity or the random number is not a good random number, you could run into trouble under certain scenarios.

It might be a better idea to use an off-the-shelf scheme for this kind of things, such as using UUIDs (which MySQL seems to support: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid ).